# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Crash in UITableView when number of rows is 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I am having a consistent crash with my UITableView when I set the number of rows in the table to zero. It crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. The crash is internal to the UITableView, so I cannot directly see what went wrong, though it should be a stupid mistake on my part.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
#0  0x0194ca60 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00656837 in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] ()
#2  0x0064c77f in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] ()
#3  0x00661450 in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] ()
#4  0x00659538 in -[UITableView layoutSubviews] ()
#5  0x00d39451 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#6  0x00d3917c in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded ()
#7  0x00d3237c in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
#8  0x00d320d0 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#9  0x00d627d5 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback ()
#10 0x013a3fbb in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#11 0x013390e7 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#12 0x01301bd7 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#13 0x01301240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#14 0x01301161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#15 0x01d42268 in GSEventRunModal ()
#16 0x01d4232d in GSEventRun ()
#17 0x005f142e in UIApplicationMain ()
#18 0x000518ec in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffef84) at /Users/megahub/xcode/QuamSec/main.m:15
```

And my code is as follows:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {

            m_oPositionTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 367) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
            m_oPositionTableView.delegate = self;
            m_oPositionTableView.dataSource = self;
            m_oPositionTableView.separatorStyle =  UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

            [self addSubview:m_oPositionTableView];

            m_oAppDelegate = (AyersGTSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        }
        return self;
    }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (m_oPositionItems == nil)
        return 0;
    else
        return [m_oPositionItems count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"QuamPortfolioPositionCell";

    QuamPortfolioPositionCell *cell = (QuamPortfolioPositionCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"QuamPortfolioPositionCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    SPPositionItem *oPositionItem = [m_oPositionItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.oSymbol.text = oPositionItem.sProdCode;
    cell.oMktPrice.text = oPositionItem.sMktPrice;
    cell.oNet.text = oPositionItem.sNet;
    cell.oAmount.text = oPositionItem.sMktVal;

    return cell;
}
```

The crash only happens when the number of rows in the table is 0. If I hardcode the number of rows returned to 1, the crash does not appear.

Comment: Turn on NSZombieEnabled, then you might be able to find out which deallocated object was accessed.

Comment: Turns out that I forgot to return a table cell in a previous initialization function. All fixed now.

Comment: You should write that as your answer, and accept it for yourself. That way the question will be marked answered, and other people searching might more easily find your solution and have a *duh* moment and fix it themselves too. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question and accept that answer (you don't get any rep for it tho ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that I forgot to return a table cell in a previous initialization function. All fixed now.

Comment: Shouldn't that have turned up as a warning when you compiled the application?

Answer (score -7):

well that's because

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

cannot return 0
That's because UITableview cannot draw an empty table without any cell

so

```
    if (m_oPositionItems == nil)
    return 1;
else
    return [m_oPositionItems count];
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Totally not true. You can absolutely have 0 rows in a section and 0 elements in a table. S/he has some other memory issue that can't really be deduced given the amount of context we have.